# coverity scan defect summary does not match outstanding defects view

Tags: coverity

I am using the online version of Coverity Scan for an open source project (rockowitz/ddcutil).  The dashboard reports a small number of outstanding defects (8 for the current build), but the Outstanding Defects view doesn't show any.  Does anyone have any idea as to the reason for the discrepancy?

Comment: I've also had this issue since January. 27 outstanding defects are reported in the dashboard view but the defect view doesn't list any of them... Wouldn't mind have an explanation for this too!

Comment: what files/functions are the defects in?  You can look in the intermediate directory output subdirectory and each checker has XML file for its found defects.  You can see the file paths there.

Comment: @asya As stated, I'm using the online version of Coverity Scan, not my own installed copy.   Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't see how I'd get access to any of these intermediate files.

Comment: @asya As stated, I'm using the online version of Coverity Scan, not my own installed copy.   Correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't see how I'd get access to any of these intermediate files.   But as suggested in Gert Woliny's  reply, the discrepancy was due to files marked as ignored

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you define components to be ignored? I have a project that has 106 outstanding defects on the dashboard, but the graphs below show that many of these defects are either in system library headers, which I set to ignore, and in the unite tests, which I also ignore because so far coverity gave too many false positives and intentional errors. These defects do not show up on the *Outstanding Defects* view.

There seems to be a change of behaviour though, because some time ago, defects in ignored components did not show up on the dashboard.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem.  I was ignoring a couple SWIG generated files.   When stopped ignoring them, the defects appeared in the Outstanding Defects view. I set the files to be ignored again, and the Outstanding Defects view is empty again.   All without submitting a new build.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I asked coverity about this issue and they said
"This is a known bug with the current release where ignored components seem to be counted. A fix is on it’s way later this week. Sorry for the inconvenience"
That was Tuesday last week